# how to Sort pd.cut (bins) in ascending order in python

Tags: python, pandas

My code is this

```
bins = [1, 1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000, 6000, 7000, 8000, 9000, 10000, 11000, 120000, 130000]
group = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13']

train['Coapplicant_Income_bin'] = pd.cut(train['CoapplicantIncome'], bins, labels=group)
Coapplicant_Income_bin = pd.crosstab(train['Coapplicant_Income_bin'], train['Loan_Status'])

print(Coapplicant_Income_bin)

Coapplicant_Income_bin.div(Coapplicant_Income_bin.sum(1).astype(float), axis=0).plot(kind="bar", stacked=True)
plt.xlabel('CoapplicantIncome')

P = plt.ylabel('Percentage')
```

**output graph:**

[image]

how to sort my bins like 1,2,3,4, ets

Comment: Your labels are strings, so just make them integers, `labels=np.arange(1,14,1)`. Or since you want consecutive integer labels anyway, just use `labels=False` and then add 1 to the labels afterward.

Comment: labels=np.arange(1,14,1) gives the same result and how to set labels=false and  add 1 to the labels afterward

Comment: Well then you are going to need to create a [mcve] to get a real answer. It's extremely difficult to know what is going on without having access to the underlying data.

Comment: For me, these are coming out sorted in my chart.

Comment: @SushantKarande - What is print(`train[['CoapplicantIncome','Loan_Status']].head(10).to_dict())` ?